# PHP equivalent of Ruby's rescue

Tags: php, ruby, sockets, try-catch, rescue

don't have enough reputation to tag this properly (ruby,PHP,socket,rescue)

I haven't practised my PHP in a long time, as I've been doing more Ruby scripting. I'm kind of embarrassed to ask for help with this.

I know, in Ruby, that I can use rescue to prevent the script from crashing in the case of error, and I'm hoping to achieve the same thing with PHP.

For example, in Ruby:

```
require 'socket'

begin puts "Connecting to host..." 
host = TCPSocket.new("169.121.77.3", 333) 
# This will (intentionally) fail to connect, triggering the rescue clause. 
rescue puts "Something went wrong." 
# Script continues to run, allowing, for example, the user to correct the host IP. 
end
```

My PHP code is a little messy - it's been quite a long time.

```
function check_alive($address,$service_port) { 
    /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */ 
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); 
    if ($socket === false) { 
      echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    } 
    else { 
      echo null; 
    } 
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port); 
    if ($result === false) { 
       echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)); 
       return 1; 
    }
    else { 
       echo null; 
    } 
    socket_close($socket); 
    return 0; } 
    $hosts = [...]; 
    // list of hosts to check 
    foreach($hosts as $key=>$host) { 
       check_alive($hosts); 
    }
```

Essentially, I have an array of hosts, and I'd like to check to see if they're alive. It's not necessary for ALL hosts to be alive, so here's where I'm stuck - the first dead host in the array crashes the script.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated - I'm willing to accept that I don't fully understand socket connections in PHP.

Comment: -1 format your code and your question! Did you try to use [*Try & catch*](http://us3.php.net/exceptions) ?

Comment: He obviously doesn't know how to format and it was his first shot at it. Don't have to downwote him on stuff like that, rather explain or do it for him.

Comment: Well, you know, good luck with PHP: http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/38

Comment: maybe try fsockopen instead: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP equivalent is:

```
try { ... } catch (...) { ... }
```

If you're using PHP 5.5, there also is:

```
try { ... } catch (...) { ... } finally { ... }
```

You can have several catch clauses, each catching a different exception class.

The finally part is *always* run, including when an exception got raised.

Comment: *Always*, unless a fatal error occurs somewhere within the try block.

Comment: Try/catch is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for reminding me. I will also look at fsockopen, thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2):

The following is the PHP equivalent for [exception handling](https://www.php.net/exceptions):

```
try { // equivalent of Ruby `begin`
    
} catch(Exception $e) { // equivalent of Ruby `rescue(e)`
    
}
```